# More elegant way of validate body in go-gin

Tags: go, go-gin

Is there a more elegant way to validate `json body` and `route id` using `go-gin`?

```golang
package controllers

import (
    "giin/inputs"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func GetAccount(context *gin.Context) {

    // validate if `accountId` is valid `uuid``
    _, err := uuid.Parse(context.Param("accountId"))
    if err != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    // some logic here...

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "account received"})
}

func AddAccount(context *gin.Context) {

    // validate if `body` is valid `inputs.Account`
    var input inputs.Account
    if error := context.ShouldBindJSON(&input); error != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, error.Error())
        return
    }

    // some logic here...

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "account added"})
}
```

I created middleware which is able to detect if `accountId` was passed and if yes validate it and return bad request if `accountId` was not in uuid format but I couldn't do the same with the body because `AccountBodyMiddleware` tries to validate every request, could someone help me with this?

And also it would be nice if I could validate any type of body instead creating new middleware for each `json body`

```golang
package main

import (
    "giin/controllers"
    "giin/inputs"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func AccountIdMiddleware(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("accountId")
    if id == "" {
        c.Next()
        return
    }
    if _, err := uuid.Parse(id); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "uuid not valid")
        c.Abort()
        return
    }
}

func AccountBodyMiddleware(c *gin.Context) {
    var input inputs.Account
    if error := c.ShouldBindJSON(&input); error != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "body is not valid")
        c.Abort()
        return
    }
    c.Next()
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(AccountIdMiddleware)
    r.Use(AccountBodyMiddleware)

    r.GET("/account/:accountId", controllers.GetAccount)
    r.POST("/account", controllers.AddAccount)
    r.Run(":5000")
}
```

Comment: You could try using groups. A group basically is a "subset" of your REST endpoints. A group can also use middlewares. A group is always attached to a path. e.g.  `/somepathwithauth` and `/somepathwithoutauth`. In this case one group would have some authentication middleware and the other one could just "do nothing"/is actually not needed. Check it out: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#grouping-routes

Comment: Maybe one more thing:  IMO middlewares are meant to be *shared* for multiple rest endpoints. If you have validation that is only needed for one rest endpoint, there is no point to use a middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I would do as you describe above.

Comment: Love your question, I've personally struggled with finding a good validation framework here, but I've settled on something I like. Will try to post an answer.

Comment: @RamiAwar, https://github.com/go-playground/validator looks quite useful for that sort of thing.

Comment: @TheFool For basic data types, yes, BUT I personally do not use it because the errors they return are very non-descriptive. Frontend would not understand them unless they had access to the backend code and knew Go, so I prefer to write the validations manually. Also, modifying them to return errors the way you want is hard, which makes it harder for new developers to learn and easier to make mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using middlewares is certainly not the way to go here, your hunch is correct! Using FastAPI as inspiration, I usually create models for every request/response that I have. You can then bind these models as query, path, or body models. An example of query model binding (just to show you that you can use this to more than just json post requests):

```golang
type User struct {
    UserId            string                     `form:"user_id"`
    Name              string                     `form:"name"`
}

func (user *User) Validate() errors.RestError {
    if _, err := uuid.Parse(id); err != nil {
        return errors.BadRequestError("user_id not a valid uuid")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Where errors is just a package you can define locally, so that can return validation errors directly in the following way:

```golang
func GetUser(c *gin.Context) {

    // Bind query model
    var q User
    if err := c.ShouldBindQuery(&q); err != nil {
        restError := errors.BadRequestError(err.Error())
        c.JSON(restError.Status, restError)
        return
    }

    // Validate request
    if err := q.Validate(); err != nil {
        c.JSON(err.Status, err)
        return
    }

    // Business logic goes here
}
```

Bonus: In this way, you can also compose structs and call internal validation functions from a high level. I think this is what you were trying to accomplish by using middlewares (composing validation):

```golang
type UserId struct {
    Id string
}

func (userid *UserId) Validate() errors.RestError {
    if _, err := uuid.Parse(id); err != nil {
        return errors.BadRequestError("user_id not a valid uuid")
    }
    return nil
}

type User struct {
    UserId
    Name string 
}

func (user *User) Validate() errors.RestError {
    if err := user.UserId.Validate(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Do some other validation
    
    return nil
}
```

Extra bonus: read more about backend route design and model-based validation here if you're interested [Softgrade - In Depth Guide to Backend Route Design](https://softgrade.org/in-depth-guide-to-backend-route-design/)

For reference, here is an example errors struct:

```golang
type RestError struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Status  int    `json:"status"`
    Error   string `json:"error"`
}

func BadRequestError(message string) *RestError {
    return &RestError{
        Message: message,
        Status:  http.StatusBadRequest,
        Error:   "Invalid Request",
    }
}
```